# Using pdfedit in linux, how do I enable the "draw rectangle" function?

Tags: linux, pdf, pdfedit

I'm using [pdfedit](http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html) on Linux.  I want to draw a rectangle over a document, but the "draw rectangle" menu item is grayed out, and the "draw rectangle" tool on the toolbar is grayed out.  I have read the documentation and am not enlightened.

Anyone know how I can turn this functionality on?  I have version 0.4.5 from Debian.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just mentioning this on the off chance that you might not mind annotating PDFs using a closed-source tool. In any case, PDF-XChange viewer is a free tool that installs and runs perfectly under Wine on Linux, and gives you full PDF annotation capabilities, including drawing, adding text and other annotations. See: http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer

Comment: Doesn't address the question about pdfedit software though.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF document may be protected somehow. In the absence of
a key or password, I have resorted to printing the whole file to
another PDF output file, and then using pdfedit on the second file,
which is now unlocked. There will be no more greyed out buttons.
I'm sure there must be better ways, but this was acceptable for me.